# css 3d vs jquery animations in terms of speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

What would you recommend for 3D animations? CSS 3D or jquery with some sort of library? I want to know in terms of time and space of execution and lagging. I want to use  some animations that use css3d for a rolling cube for example. What would be better? Jquery or css? I think it would be easier with jquery because it can be more easy to manipulate those animations but int terms of efficiency? I researched and i found out that css uses hardware acceleration but some people say that jquery might be less laggy. What would you recommend? I found here on stackoverflow this link that shows the speed but there's no css method:
https://greensock.com/js/speed.html

Answer (score 0):

In depends of what 3D animations you want to do.

If it's something +/- simple CSS is the way, CSS is *always* smoother than javascript. The problem you might have with CSS is the support through different older browsers. Javascript is safer on that point. But I think each case is a different case. What do you plan to build with 3D?

Comment: i want to make an animation that uses transform rotatex and rotatey and this can't be done only with jquery, i need some other library for it in order to make it work and for example i have a div that will be loaded with content via ajax and that div will be animated with css 3D. that div will be fliped in some way. And i think if i have to add another library it will work harder than trough css but in css i have problems because i have multiple nested animations that should work on the same time/after an event etc

Comment: if only want to flip and rotatex and rotatey you can use only css. the other stuff (load and ajax), you will need js. See this codepen profile from Ana Tudor. http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pens/popular/, most of her codepens are css only